# How to force xdebug to only trace one request

Tags: php, ajax, xdebug

I'm using xdebug for an Ajax request and the `js` file will redirect after the end of the current request, I want to limit xdebug to just show me my current request and actually i need to find most last lines which return stuff to the js. but it just jumps weirdly around when redirect happens and i can't distinguish these two requests.

Comment: You can try to make the ajax request manually without JS or put breakpoint in the js script in browser before any redirect (or just after sending the request) so you get only one request.

Comment: @Dukecz i don't see redirect point, i don't know how the `js` code implemented, and the `php ` code has CSRF tokens so i don't know how could i do request without using browser :-?

Comment: @Dukecz BTW even with these options which has a little more works to do, i want to know if xdebug has options like this or not.

Comment: granted xdebug is part of it, but ... this is mostly a function of your xdebug client.  For example, in PhpStorm, i can place conditions for pausing a breakpoint, or skipping it. Look around in your IDE for such capabilities.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I use VSC, and xdebug extension here looks a little bit minimalistic and just has 6 button to stop, run, step out etc... I can't find anything that could help me with my problem. and i actually never used Phpstorm.

Comment: NetBeans (freeware) is full-featured as well.

Comment: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions - `xdebug_break` or configure xdebug in .htaccess within `<files>` section? What do you want?

Comment: @no0ob You can use breakpoints as shown here I believe: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_debug-menu. If you don't know at all which functions are called and where then you can try to run a profiler in order to get the function call tree.

Comment: @Dukecz Nice, but still I can't find a way to distinguish the requests using these features.